# Controlling what godoc documents in a repo that is not just Go packages

Tags: go, godoc

I have a Go sub-project in a multi-language project repo. I want to be able to use 'go get' and 'go doc'.

My layout looks like:

```
proton-c/bindings/go/<my packages>
examples/go/<some go examples>
```

I set up go-import  tags on the website and created a "go" symlink in the repo root so I can `go get qpid.apache.org/proton/go/<package>`. It works!! It clones the entire project repo into my GOPATH but that's ok.

The problem is if I run godoc -http it does the following bad things:

- ignores the root "go" symlink entirely
- documents my packages as "qpid.apache.org/proton/proton-c/bindings/go/"
- shows the package path to the directory with nothing in it.

The command line "godoc qpid.apache.org/proton/go/package" DOES do the right thing so godoc can extract the doc correctly but the "directory browsing" feature of godoc -http is picking up too much and not following the symlink.
So can I restrict/control what godoc picks as documentation?

I read https://github.com/golang/gddo/wiki/Source-Code-Links, but I don't think it helps my problem, could be wrong.